# Were Elves half the size of Humans?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, elves, the-hobbit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are Tolkien Elves taller or shorter than Men?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10804/are-tolkien-elves-taller-or-shorter-than-men)

[image: Standard Elf]

This sketch by [Colin Williams](http://tolkiensketches.com/) suggests that elves were half the size of a human. Also they are much more 'alien-like' than Peter Jackson's version.

Are these sketches accurate to Tolkien's idea of the elves?

Comment: If that sketch is meant to be of a Tolkien Elf it is very very wrong.

Comment: Elves are meant to be creatures of great beauty. This is just... not.

Comment: Mr. Williams sketches are "inspired by the writings" of Tolkein, but so far I don't see much evidence that he uses Tolkein's descriptions to drive his sketches. Both his elves and his hobbits look all wrong.

Comment: General rule - "inspired by" seems to mean "no relation at all" for most people's work

Comment: Is this like a middle schooler's website or something?  These drawings are terrible!

Comment: To be fair to Collins, he says right on his front page that he based most of his early work on the Hobbit, and the Wood-elves aren't exactly described in detail.

Comment: @Wlerin - but they are described as "fair", i.e., beautiful.  This monstrosity is not fair.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Elves were at least as tall as Men.

Here's an earlier discussion:

[Are Tolkien Elves taller or shorter than Men?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10804/are-tolkien-elves-taller-or-shorter-than-men)

There's also a notion that Númenóreans, who were very tall Men, were sometimes confused as Elves by the Men in Middle-earth:

https://valarguild.org/varda/Tolkien/encyc/papers/heights.htm