# What kind of bow did the Tolkien's Elves use?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/71651/976) seems to imply that it was a longbow.

Is there canon information on what kind of bow would Elves use? (and if so, was it different for different Elvish groups?)

Comment: I don't recall any mention of crossbows, so some type of longbow, either simple or recurve. [Recurve bows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurve_bow) are more elegant-looking so elves in general are often depicted using them, but there's no canonical Tolkien information on the subject.

Comment: "they laid Beleg in a shallow grave, and placed beside him Belthronding his great bow, that was made of black yew-wood."  Yew was the preferred wood for the legendary English Longbow.  I'm guessing elves used longbows exclusively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no one single type.

The Teleri in Valinor are described in the Silmarillion chapter *Of the Flight of the Noldor*:

> For the Noldor were become fierce and desperate, and the Teleri had less strength, and were armed for the most part but with slender bows.

Beleg Strongbow has something a bit more substantial (from *Of Túrin Turambar*):

> ...they laid Beleg in a shallow grave, and placed beside him Belthronding his great bow, that was made of black yew-wood.

The difference between the bows of Mirkwood Elves and those of Lórien Elves is described at Galadriel's gift-giving in Lord of the Rings:

> To Legolas she gave a bow such as the Galadhrim used, longer and stouter than the bows of Mirkwood, and strung with a string of elf-hair.

But in general Tolkien doesn't really describe this kind of level of detail, except where it's important to the plot.  There are other references where only possession of a bow is mentioned without specification of type: "Fingon strung an arrow, and bent his bow", "Curufin, being filled with shame and malice, took the bow of Celegorm".